# How to use fallback for some specific value, instead of undefined, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, fallback

I want to use Javascript variable fallback to assign default value when a particular condition is met, instead of undefined.

I understand I can use simple if-else to achieve the same result. I want to know whether I can use fallback for it or not. For example, can I do something like:

```
var cat = 'cat';
var animal = (cat == 'cat') || ('dog');
```

which currently gives,

```
Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I want something with functionality similar to

```
var cat = 'cat';
if(cat==='cat')
{
    var animal = cat;
} else 
{
    var animal = 'dog';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want the conditional operator:

```
var animal = cat == 'cat' ? cat : 'dog';
```

If you *really really* wanted to use `||` for this, you could chain a `&& cat` onto the `cat === 'cat'`, and then alternate with `'dog'`:

```js
var cat = 'cat';
var animal = (cat === 'cat' && cat) || 'dog';
console.log(animal);
```

(please don't do this, though)

Comment: Your answer is similar to the if condition. I want to know, whether I can achieve it using fallback or || operator.

Comment: You *could* achieve it using `||`, in a roundabount and ugly way, but I wouldn't recommend it at all - the conditional operator is exactly the right tool for this job.

Comment: I understand it would be an ugly way but, still can you tell me how to achieve it?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a value if the condition is met and use the default value.

```
var animal = cat === 'cat' && cat || 'dog';
```

Comment: Sooooo... why?!

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted.